# C++ Why can't I use swap on an object with a deleted default constructor

Tags: c++, move-semantics, default-constructor, rvalue, move-constructor

I am trying to implement a move constructor for object A that uses the class Id. Class Id is automatically generated and for future coding sanity I chose to delete the default constructor when I do so.

Yet when I try to use swap in the move constructor of A it is complaining that the **default constructor of Id is deleted**. I thought swap wasn't constructing any new objects, but merely swapping the addresses of the two items.

Have I misunderstood it and it is actually creating a third temporary instance of Id??

If that is the case what is the best way to go about implementing the move constructor below?

I have included a minimal example below:

```
class Id {

public:
    Id() = delete;
    Id(std::string id) : m_id(id) {}

private:
    std::string m_id;
};

class A {

public:
    A() = delete;
    A(Id id) : m_id(id) {}


    A(A&& other) {
        std::swap(m_id, other.m_id);
    }

private:
    Id m_id;
};
```

the compiler returns the following error:

```
In constructor 'A::A(A&&)':
21:18: error: use of deleted function 'Id::Id()'
8:5: note: declared here
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_pair.h:59:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39,
                 from 2:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/move.h: In instantiation of 'void std::swap(_Tp&, _Tp&) [with _Tp = A]':
34:17:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/move.h:176:11: error: use of deleted function 'A& A::operator=(const A&)'
       __a = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(__b);
           ^
15:7: note: 'A& A::operator=(const A&)' is implicitly declared as deleted because 'A' declares a move constructor or move assignment operator
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_pair.h:59:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39,
                 from 2:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/move.h:177:11: error: use of deleted function 'A& A::operator=(const A&)'
       __b = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(__tmp);
```

Comment: How can SWAP do its work in one step?

Answer (score 6):

You *can* use `swap` on the `Id`objects, the problem isn't there, but in the constructor of `A`.

```
A(A&& other) {
    std::swap(m_id, other.m_id);
}
```

This is default constructing an `Id`, and then swapping it with the member of the other `A`.

To avoid the default constructor, you have to initialize the `Id` in the initializer list

```
A(A&& other) : m_id(std::move(other.m_id))
{  }
```